# Chartjs working with large and small values

Tags: angularjs, chart.js, angular-chart

I'm using Chartjs and Angular(angular-chart.js) and I need a way to show my graphs in a better way. My graphs have data with too much variation:
[Graph image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vi81i.png)

There are any way I can group some Ticks of the graph? Like the interval of 200 - 400 with just one Tick. Or there are any other way to deal with it?

Answer (score 0):

Can you create the plunkr to reproduce this issue or you can try  this, 
[Linear Scale config](http://www.chartjs.org/docs/#scales-linear-scale)

```js
var chartInstance = new Chart(ctx, {
    type: 'line',
    data: data,
    options: {
        scales: {
            yAxes: [{
                ticks: {
                    max: 5,
                    min: 0,
                    stepSize: 0.5
                }
            }]
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I got this [IMAGE](https://s32.postimg.org/7hjoiohsl/graph2.png). I already tried this solution and the logarithmic scale too. The problem is the variation of the data. One thing that I think that will solve this problem is hiding some ticks, maybe the ticks from 200 to 400, because they are there just because of the bigger column data. You got it?

Comment: Yeah some what. It wud be great if you provide any plunk.